# Purpose of capacitor in melody generator IC

Tags: capacitor

What is the purpose fo the capacitor in the following circuit?

[image: M66T circuit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitor is to stabilize the supply voltage for the Melody IC. It allows the supply to stay steady at sudden current draws.

Comment: Like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor#Transient_load_decoupling?

Comment: Yes, exactly a decoupling capacitor :)